# Convert to AIFC with ima4 compression

Tags: file-conversion

A lot of audio programs, such as *Audacity*, support encoding files as AIFF ([Audio Interchange File Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_Interchange_File_Format), developed by *Apple Inc.*).

However, I need specifically an AIFF file that has been *compressed with ima4*, making it an AIFC file.

The internet seems to be nearly clueless about AIFC and ima4. "convert to AIFC" (with quotes) yields exactly 0 results on Google (3M for MP3, 90K for WAV, 45K for FLAC, ...).

Possible solutions:

- **ffmpeg**. I know `ffmpeg -i wavefile.wav -f aiff wavefile.aiff` converts to AIFF but I can't figure out how to specify the compression algorithm.
- **afconvert**. According to [here](http://alexanderwong.me/post/67897096418/convert-wav-to-compressed-aifc-for-ios), we can use `afconvert -f AIFC -d ima4 [file]`. But this is a Mac-only program and I only have access to Windows and Linux Mint machines.
- **afftools**. [See here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/how-to-install-afconvert-on-fedora-888841/). This strangely seems to be a Fedora-only program, and I once again can't find anything on it on Google (if it even does what I want).
- **Adobe Audition**. [See here](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2244942). Once again I do not own this paid-for software.

Comment: I should add that, in my tests, VLC had no problem playing AIFC ima4 encoded files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I thought I'd take a crack at an ffmpeg solution since it's always proved itself to be infinitely versatile for me.

A cursory search of the ffmpeg docs found no useful references to *ima4*. However, I then realised that *ima4* refers to the [**ADPCM IMA QuickTime**](https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php/Apple_QuickTime_IMA_ADPCM) codec. Back to the ffmpeg docs, and this appears on the list of [supported audio codecs](https://www.ffmpeg.org/general.html#Audio-Codecs).

Now we know what ffmpeg thinks the codec is called, but not how to refer to it. Running `ffmpeg -encoders` produces a list of all codecs for which encoding is supported, along with their identifiers. In our case, we can see:

```
$ ffmpeg -encoders | grep "ADPCM IMA QuickTime"
 A..... adpcm_ima_qt         ADPCM IMA QuickTime
```

Great! Now we know to tell ffmpeg to use the *adpcm_ima_qt* codec. Which is as simple as:

```
$ ffmpeg -i file.wav -c:a adpcm_ima_qt file.aiff
Input #0, wav, from 'file.wav':
  Duration: 00:00:54.31, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16le (native) -> adpcm_ima_qt (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, aiff, to 'file.aiff':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.12.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: adpcm_ima_qt (ima4 / 0x34616D69), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 352 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.18.100 adpcm_ima_qt
size=    2485kB time=00:00:54.31 bitrate= 374.9kbits/s speed= 306x
video:0kB audio:2485kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.002829%
```

The `-c:a` option is the same as specifying `-acodec`; both of these specify the codec to encode audio streams with.

And finally a quick inspection with ffprobe (note *ima4* on line 3):

```
$ ffprobe file.aiff
Input #0, aiff, from 'file.aiff':
  Duration: 00:00:54.31, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 374 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: adpcm_ima_qt (ima4 / 0x34616D69), 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16p, 352 kb/s
```

Comment: I actually tried out ffmpeg but I was only searching for "Apple" and "AIFF", not "QuickTime" =D   brb giving this a try!

Comment: Any way to set _bit depth_ using this? The `sample_fmt` option with `s16p` doesn't work (bit rate stays 4, according to `mediainfo`)

Comment: From [this reference page](https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php/IMA_ADPCM) on the underlying codec: "*The encoded IMA bitstream is comprised of a series of 4-bit nibbles.*" The bit depth appears to be hardcoded into the codec.

Comment: So you are saying this is part of the _specification_ and not just the _implementation_ ffmpeg uses? How come my reference file has a bit depth of 16 then?

Comment: That's what it looks like to me. I'm not sure, is that what mediainfo is saying?

Comment: Yes. And you can see it in the header too, at the expected place, I compared the hexdump to the specification (http://www.onicos.com/staff/iz/formats/aiff.html). I've made progress and think the bit depth isn't required anymore, although I'm still getting crashes, but I think they're unrelated to the bit depth xd

Comment: What's the context here? What program needs these specifically encoded files?

Comment: That specification is for the AIFF container format, not the ADPCM IMA codec

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed the crashes, everything is dandy now  thanks again =)